# Получение статуса пользователя (онлайне/нет) для пользователя бота Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Не могу найти в API запрос, для получения статуса пользователя для обещния с ботом. Т.е. нужно реализовать логику отправки сообщения, только если собеседни "онлайн"

Answer (score 2):

В текущих реализациях Telegram Bot API и Telegram API это невозможно. Если очень надо, то стоит посмотреть на [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg), в частности - на команду **user_info**.

> **user_info** `user` Prints info about user (id, last online, phone)

Comment: Потыкал telegram-cli . Уже лучше. НО! Стоит телеграмм на телефоне "свернуть" (запущен фоново), user_info уже показывает offline

Comment: Ну так а Вы что хотели? Возьмите телефон у друга и посмотрите свой статус в этот момент, там будет то же самое.

Comment: Онлайн  - значит пользователь видит интерфейс. Если пользователь свернул интерфейс, то уже "last seen". По-моему во всех мессенджерах это аналогично реализовано. Во всяком случае в ватсапе точно так же.

Comment: "мы хотели" знать, стоит отправлять пользователю сообщение или нет. Если у него нет сейчас интернета, телефон выключен и т.п. - то не отправлять. Иначе - отправлять. Прикручиваю к заббиксу сиё.. Таким образом статус "оффлайн" не говорит нам о том что пользователь НЕ может получить сообщение.. Возможно у него телеграм просто "свернут". Но возможно он сейчас и не может получить сообщение по причине того что "нет интернета".